# EPPlus SUMIFS return value #VALUE

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I am generating excel file with EPPlus. at the end i am try to get sum of values of a column but getting **#VALUE!**

i used SUM formula first but got the same error. Here is a sample code.

```
for (int x = 2; x <= totalIteration; x++)
{
    startperiodletter = ColumnIndexToColumnLetter(x) + 2;
    endperiodletter = ColumnIndexToColumnLetter(x) + totalrows;
    tmpCell = ColumnIndexToColumnLetter(x) + (totalrows+1);

    ws.Cells[tmpCell].Formula = "=SUMIFS(B2:B99,B2:B99,>0)";
    ws.Cells[tmpCell].Calculate();
    val = (ws.Cells[tmpCell].Value == null ? "" : ws.Cells[tmpCell].Value.ToString());
}
```

**ws.Cells[tmpCell].Formula = "=SUMIFS(B2:B99,B2:B99,>0)";** This way i use **SUMIF formula with EPPLus** and when i try to read value then getting value like **#VALUE!** i am reading value this way **val = (ws.Cells[tmpCell].Value == null ? "" : ws.Cells[tmpCell].Value.ToString());**

this line is not working as expected.
my few cells are empty and i want to get sum of those cell value which is not empty.

please rectify me where i made the mistake in above code.

Comment: `>0` is not a valid argument for `SUMIFS`. `">0"` would be.

Comment: How to mention not equal to blank with SUMIF....syntax please. thanks

Comment: @GSerg still getting same error after following your suggestion. here is the code `ws.Cells[tmpCell].Formula = "=SUMIFS(" + startperiodletter + ":" + endperiodletter + "," + startperiodletter + ":" + endperiodletter + ",\"\">0\"\")";`

Comment: i change my formula again ` ws.Cells[tmpCell].Formula = @"=SUMIFS(B2:B99,"""">0"""")";`  I assume EPPlus does not support SUMIF function because it return #VALUE! this value always.